# Как добавить в Куки порядковый номер товара?

Tags: php

```
            <?php 
 $date = [
 [
    'title' => 'Бегония',
    'price_val' => 300,
    'number' => 75,
 ],
 [
    'title' => 'Белый лотос',
    'price_val' => 400,
    'number' => 21,
  ],


    <tr><?php foreach($date as $key => $item): ?>
        <td><?=$item['title']?></td>
        <td><?=$item['price_val']?></td>
        <form action="cart_add.php" metod="GET"></form>
    <td><a href="cart_add.php?buy_item=<?=$key++?>">buy</a></td>
    </tr>     
    //Файл cart_add.php проверяет, указан ли GET параметр buy_item и если он указан, добавляет в куки 
     порядковый номер товара, в массив user_cart. 
      //на другом файле
      <?php
    if(!empty($_GET['buy_item'])){
    setcookie('user_cart', (int)'$key', '/', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 *30 );
       }
      print_r($_COOKIE);
       ?>
       //ошибка и не работает.
```

Comment: (int)'$key' а чё здесь в одинарных кавычках?

Comment: setcookie() видимо отправляет куки, а доступны print_r($_COOKIE) они будут только при следующей загрузке страницы

Comment: вниматьельнее изучи https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie